# Java : How to get the certificate information from web service server on HTTPS request in 2-ways SSL?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm using SOAP Axis2 Web Service with 2-ways SSL.

In client side, I have set the SSL enviroment using the code given below:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePass);

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePass);

    System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs",
            "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
```

In server side, I want to get the information of keystore certificate (serial number, common name, ...).

**How can I do it?**

Comment: The client certificate, if present, is available via a request attribute documented in the Servlet specification. NB The last of those properties hasn't been required for nearly 20 years.

Comment: I don't really understand, what exactly do you want to say? What attributes can I use to get certificate client from server?